# How to merge .doc files using Apache POI API

Tags: java, apache-poi

i'm trying to merge .doc files , i used this code found in previous stackOverflow post :

```
        public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {  
        // POI apparently can't create a document from scratch,  
        // so we need an existing empty dummy document  
        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("fich1.doc"));  
        Range range = doc.getRange();  


        //I can get the entire Document and insert it in the tmp.doc  
        //However any formatting in my word document is lost.  
        HWPFDocument doc2 = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("fich2.doc"));  
        Range range2 = doc2.getRange();  
        range.insertAfter(range2.text());  

        //I can get the information (text only) for each character run/paragraph or section.  
        //Again any formatting in my word document is lost.  
        HWPFDocument doc3 = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("fich3.doc"));  
        Range range3 = doc3.getRange();  
        for(int i=0;i<range3.numCharacterRuns();i++){  
            CharacterRun run3 = range3.getCharacterRun(i);  
            range.insertAfter(run3.text());  
        }  

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("result.doc");  
        doc.write(out);  
        out.flush();  
        out.close();  
}
```

The problem that i'm getting this error :

> `Your document seemed to be mostly unicode, but the section definition was in bytes! Trying anyway, but things may well go wrong!
>   Your document seemed to be mostly unicode, but the section definition was in bytes! Trying anyway, but things may well go wrong!
>   Your document seemed to be mostly unicode, but the section definition was in bytes! Trying anyway, but things may well go wrong!`

Here's the content of the different files :

**fich1.doc :** Hi all

**fich2.doc :** Bonjour à tous

**fich3.doc :** Hallo alles

**resullt.doc :** Hi allB

Comment: What result do you *want*?

Comment: result.doc is the fich1 content append fich2 and fich3.

Answer (score 1):

This bug is fixed in poi 3.9 jars : used jars

> poi-3.9.jar  / poi-ooxml-3.9.jar  / poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar  / poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar