# Apache Poi: Text is added to .doc file before it's content but not after it

Tags: java, apache-poi

i need to add a simple text (From another .txt or .doc file) to a .doc file the code is very simple :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("/home/amira/work/APPS-579/word/test1.doc"));
HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);

Range range = doc.getRange();

CharacterRun run = range.insertAfter("Hello World!!! It works well!!!");
run.setBold(true);
run.setItalic(true);
run.setCapitalized(true);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/home/amira/work/APPS-579/word/sampleAfter.doc");
doc.write(out);
out.flush();
out.close();
}
```

The new sampleAfter.doc is created but only contains the content of test1.doc : the "Hello World!!! It works well!!!" string has not been added .

I tried so to use the

> range.insertBefore(String text)

method so it works and the string is added before the content of test1.doc.

I really don't get it. 
Is there an explanation for this issue.

Here's the content of test1.doc :

> Voilà mon premier test le 24/03/24

Here's the result of : `System.out.println(range.text());`

**With an insertBefore :**

> 1. Hello World!!! It works well!!!Voilà mon premier test le 24/03/24

**With an insertAfter :**

```
Voilà mon premier test le 24/03/24 

Hello World!!! It works well!!!
```

Comment: What version of Apache POI is this with?

Comment: @Gagravarr the last one 3.9, because i had this issue with previous versions of poi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564664/how-to-merge-doc-files-using-apache-poi-api/22607078#22607078

Comment: Have you tried with the latest one, i.e. 3.10?

Comment: no i didn't but i think it's not a version issue

Answer (score 1):

Well, the above code seems to work for me. I guess it would be better to follow the following approach

```
Range r1 = doc.getRange();
Section sec = r1.getSection(r1.numSections()-1);
Paragraph para = sec.getParagraph(sec.numParagraphs()-1);
CharacterRun run = para.getCharacterRun(para.numCharacterRuns()-1);
run.insertAfter("Hello World!!! It works well!!!");
run.setBold(true);
run.setItalic(true);
run.setCapitalized(true);
```

Comment: thank u, but i have a question did you get the same problem when writing the code i used?

Comment: No, I didn't get that issue.